# Extended dict-like subclass to support casting and JSON dumping without extras

Tags: python, json, dictionary, casting

I need to create an instance `t` of a dict-like class `T` that supports
both "casting" to a real dict with `dict(**t)`, without reverting to doing 
`dict([(k, v) for k, v in t.items()])`. As well as supports dumping as
JSON using the standard `json` library, without extending the normal JSON
Encoder (i.e. no function provided for the `default` parameter).

With `t` being a normal `dict`, both work:

```
import json

def dump(data):
    print(list(data.items()))
    try:
        print('cast:', dict(**data))
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR:', e)
    try:
        print('json:', json.dumps(data))
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR:', e)

t = dict(a=1, b=2)
dump(t)
```

printing:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
cast: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
json: {"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

However I want `t` to be an instance of the class `T` that adds e.g. a
key `default` *"on the fly"* to its items, so no inserting up-front is possible (actually I want merged keys
from one or more instances of T to show up, this is a simplification of that real,
much more complex, class).

```
class T(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'default':
           return 'DEFAULT'
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    def items(self):
        for k in dict.keys(self):
            yield k, self[k]
        yield 'default', self['default']

    def keys(self):
        for k in dict.keys(self):
            yield k 
        yield 'default'

t = T(a=1, b=2)
dump(t)
```

this gives:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('default', 'DEFAULT')]
cast: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
json: {"a": 1, "b": 2, "default": "DEFAULT"}
```

and the cast doesn't work properly because there is no key 'default',
and I don't know which "magic" function to provide to make casting
work.

When I build `T` upon the functionality that `collections.abc` implements, and provide the
required abstract methods in the subclass, casting works:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class TIter:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.keys = list(t.d.keys()) + ['default']
        self.index = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == len(self.keys):
            raise StopIteration
        res = self.keys[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return res

class T(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.d = dict(**kw)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if key != 'default':
            del self.d[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.d) + 1

    def __setitem__(self, key, v):
        if key != 'default':
            self.d[key] = v

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'default':
           return 'DEFAULT'
        # return None
        return self.d[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return TIter(self)

t = T(a=1, b=2)
dump(t)
```

which gives:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('default', 'DEFAULT')]
cast: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'default': 'DEFAULT'}
ERROR: Object of type 'T' is not JSON serializable
```

The JSON dumping fails because that dumper cannot handle
`MutableMapping` subclasses, it explicitly tests on the C level using `PyDict_Check`.

When I tried to make `T` a subclass of both `dict` and
`MutableMapping`, I did get the same result as when using only
the `dict` subclass.

I can of course consider it  a bug that the `json` dumper has not
been updated to assume that (concrete subclasses of)
`collections.abc.Mapping` are dumpable. But even if it is acknowledged
as a bug and gets fixed in some future version of Python, I don't think
such a fix will be applied to older versions of Python.

**Q1**: How can I make the `T` implementation that is a subclass of
`dict`, to cast properly?
**Q2**: If Q1 doesn't have an answer, would it
work if I make a C level class that returns the right value for
`PyDict_Check` but doesn't do any of the actual implementation (and
then make `T` a subclass of that as well as `MutableMapping` (I don't
think adding such an incomplete C level dict will work, but I haven't
tried), and would this fool `json.dumps()`?
**Q3** Is this a complete wrong approach to get both to work like the first example?

---

The actual code, that is
much more complex, is a part of my `ruamel.yaml` library which has to
work on Python 2.7 and Python 3.4+.

As long as I can't solve this, I have to tell people that used to have
functioning JSON dumpers (without extra arguments) to use:

```
def json_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
        return obj._od
    if isinstance(obj, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq):
        return obj._lst
    raise TypeError

print(json.dumps(d, default=json_default))
```

, tell them to use a different loader than the default (round-trip) loader. E.g.:

```
yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(stream)
```

, implements some `.to_json()` method on the class `T` and make users
of `ruamel.yaml` aware of that

, or go back to subclassing `dict` and have tell people to do

```
 dict([(k, v) for k, v in t.items()])
```

none of which is really friendly and would indicate it is impossible
to make a dict-like class that is non-trivial and cooperates well with the standard
library.

Comment: 3 things I want to point out: 1) Your `__iter__` or `__next__` method is incorrect; trying to iterate over a `T` instance is an infinite loop. You cannot implement the `__next__` method with `yield`. If you want to use `yield`, use it in `__iter__`. 2) All those occurences of `dict.keys(self)` would be better written as `super().keys()` because then you don't have to hard-code the parent class in 4 different places. 3) All those `for x in y: yield x` should be written as `yield from y`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Regarding 1) that is left over from some try-out. I removed that. for the other subclassing this is done without `yield`. Are you sure that 2 and 3 work on Python 2.7 as well?

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you had to support python 2.7. (There's too much text to read!)

Comment: Sorry for that. I tried to be complete and still allow cut and pasting for those who want to try things. And that is kind of difficult in this case. Come 2020 I'll clean up my code ;-)

Comment: As far as I understand, the issue boils down to how to provide additional keys during expansion of `**data` in your `dump()`. Did you try to examine CPython sources to see which hooks (magic functions) are considered during this expansion?

Comment: @KirillBulygin I did look at `dict_merge` in `dictobject.c` as I don't think that `**data` does actual expansion, but it might. Searching for `**` is the C source is not an easy task. `dict_merge` takes some shortcuts and does not do anything above the C level if calling `PyDict_Check` on the object returns True. Maybe the only real solution is implementing this dict-like object in C, and I am not looking forward to doing that kind of an excercise again (and now for both 2.7 and 3.4+) That would also not really help users of Jython and pypy

Comment: I just suspect that your `dump()` function can't work even with versions of CPython you want to support. I'm not familiar with CPython internals, but this might help: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb.

Answer (score 3):

Since the real problem here is really `json.dumps`'s default encoder's inability to consider `MutableMapping` (or `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` in your real-world example) as a dict, instead of telling people to set the `default` parameter of `json.dumps` to your `json_default` function like you mentioned, you can use `functools.partial` to make `json_default` a default value for the `default` parameter of `json.dumps` so that people don't have to do anything differently when they use your package:

```
from functools import partial
json.dumps = partial(json.dumps, default=json_default)
```

Or if you need to allow people to specify their own `default` parameter or even their own `json.JSONEncoder` subclass, you can use a wrapper around `json.dumps` so that it wraps the `default` function specified by the `default` parameter and the `default` method of the custom encoder specified by the `cls` parameter, whichever one is specified:

```
import inspect

class override_json_default:
    # keep track of the default methods that have already been wrapped
    # so we don't wrap them again
    _wrapped_defaults = set()

    def __call__(self, func):
        def override_default(default_func):
            def default_wrapper(o):
                o = default_func(o)
                if isinstance(o, MutableMapping):
                    o = dict(o)
                return o
            return default_wrapper

        def override_default_method(default_func):
            def default_wrapper(self, o):
                try:
                    return default_func(self, o)
                except TypeError:
                    if isinstance(o, MutableMapping):
                        return dict(o)
                    raise
            return default_wrapper

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            bound.apply_defaults()
            default = bound.arguments.get('default')
            if default:
                bound.arguments['default'] = override_default(default)
            encoder = bound.arguments.get('cls')
            if not default and not encoder:
                bound.arguments['cls'] = encoder = json.JSONEncoder
            if encoder:
                default = getattr(encoder, 'default')
                if default not in self._wrapped_defaults:
                    default = override_default_method(default)
                    self._wrapped_defaults.add(default)
                setattr(encoder, 'default', default)
            return func(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)

        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        return wrapper

json.dumps=override_json_default()(json.dumps)
```

so that the following test code with both a custom `default` function and a custom encoder that handle `datetime` objects, as well as one without a custom `default` or encoder:

```
from datetime import datetime

def datetime_encoder(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime):
        return o.isoformat()
    return o

class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()
        return super(DateTimeEncoder, self).default(o)

def dump(data):
    print(list(data.items()))
    try:
        print('cast:', dict(**data))
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR:', e)
    try:
        print('json with custom default:', json.dumps(data, default=datetime_encoder))
        print('json wtih custom encoder:', json.dumps(data, cls=DateTimeEncoder))
        del data['c']
        print('json without datetime:', json.dumps(data))
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR:', e)

t = T(a=1, b=2, c=datetime.now())
dump(t)
```

would all give the proper output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 23, 59, 25, 575642)), ('default', 'DEFAULT')]
cast: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 23, 59, 25, 575642), 'default': 'DEFAULT'}
json with custom default: {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "2018-09-15T23:59:25.575642", "default": "DEFAULT"}
json wtih custom encoder: {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "2018-09-15T23:59:25.575642", "default": "DEFAULT"}
json without datetime: {"a": 1, "b": 2, "default": "DEFAULT"}
```

As pointed out in the comments, the above code uses `inspect.signature`, which is not available until Python 3.3, and even then, `inspect.BoundArguments.apply_defaults` is not available until Python 3.5, and the [`funcsigs`](https://pypi.org/project/funcsigs/) package, a backport of Python 3.3's `inspect.signature`, does not have the `apply_defaults` method either. To make the code as backward-compatible as possible, you can simply copy and paste the code of Python 3.5+'s [`inspect.BoundArguments.apply_defaults`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py#L2669) to your module and assign it as an attribute of `inspect.BoundArguments` after importing `funcsigs` as necessary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

if not hasattr(inspect, 'signature'):
    import funcsigs
    for attr in funcsigs.__all__:
        setattr(inspect, attr, getattr(funcsigs, attr))

if not hasattr(inspect.BoundArguments, 'apply_defaults'):
    def apply_defaults(self):
        arguments = self.arguments
        new_arguments = []
        for name, param in self._signature.parameters.items():
            try:
                new_arguments.append((name, arguments[name]))
            except KeyError:
                if param.default is not funcsigs._empty:
                    val = param.default
                elif param.kind is funcsigs._VAR_POSITIONAL:
                    val = ()
                elif param.kind is funcsigs._VAR_KEYWORD:
                    val = {}
                else:
                    continue
                new_arguments.append((name, val))
        self.arguments = OrderedDict(new_arguments)

    inspect.BoundArguments.apply_defaults = apply_defaults
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as extending the default JSON Encoder. This might work for some, but it uses up the `default` parameter which is most likely provided by the people using json themselves (e.g. to handle datetime objects).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a decorator that decorates `default` function and custom encoder so that people can use their own if desired. Please try it out and let me know if you still see any issues.

Comment: The wrapping of json.dumps in the updated answer looks like an acceptable solution. I made two changes to get this to work properly: `default_func` needs to be called first (in case it can handle  `MutableMapping`) and when it raises `TypeError` catch that and do `if instance(o, MutableMapping): return dict(o)` and else (re-)raise the `TypeError`. If the user doesn't provide either default no handler for `MutableMapping` is installed, so I changed `wrapper` to install `override_default` if neither is provided and have `override_default` handle a `default_func is None` by raising TypeError.

Comment: Shall I update your code with these fixes? With them this is what I consider an acceptable answer, and I don't want to post my updated version as an answer, where you have done most of the hard work. I can also get you a link to the modified code if you want.

Comment: Thanks for carefully reviewing my code and making very valid points. I've updated my answer accordingly. Also note that I have now made `override_json_default` a class instead so that it can have the `_wrapped_defaults` set attribute to keep track of the methods it has wrapped to avoid re-wrapping them.

Comment: FYI: `signature` is not available on Python 2.7 or 3.4. While `signature` is available from a backport package `fundsign`, since it is a backport of 3.3 functionality it doesn't have `apply_defaults` (which is also not on available in pypy).

Comment: Good point about compatibility issues with Python 3.4 and earlier. I've updated my answer to address them and have fully tested the updated code in Python 2.7. As you must already know, there's no `MutableMapping` in Python 2.7 so I had to make your `T` inherit `UserDict.UserDict` and make it use `self.data` instead of `self.d`. Also note that `override_json_default` now has to be instantiated first before using it as a wrapper because Python 2.7 enforces compatibility of `__init__` and `__new__`, preventing me from simply using `__new__` as a wrapper.

Comment: I got my solution from the [example in 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments).  [MutableMappings are in 2.7, just in another place](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMap)

Comment: I see. I've removed the mention of the issue with `MutableMappings` in 2.7 from my answer then. I'll leave my `apply_defaults` code in the answer though, just in case someone is interested in using the `apply_defaults` method in older code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to Q1 and Q2 are: "You cannot" resp. "No"

In short: you cannot add a key on-the-fly within Python and have JSON output
as well (without patching json.dumps or providing a `default` to it).

The reason for that is that for JSON to work at all, you need to make
your class a subclass of `dict` (or some other object implemented at
the C level) so that its call of `PyDict_Check()` returns non-zero
(which means the tp_flags field in the objectheader has the
Py_TPFLAGS_DICT_SUBCLASS bit set).

The cast (`dict(**data))`) first does this check on the C level as
well (in `dictobject.c:dict_merge`). But there is a difference in how
things proceed from there. When dumping JSON the code actually
iterates over the key/values using routines provided by the subclass
if these are available.

On the contrary the cast doesn't look if there is any subclassing
going on and copies the values from the C level implementation (
`dict`, `ruamel.ordereddict`, etc.).

When casting something that is not a subclass of `dict`, then the
normal Python class level interface (`__iter__`) is called to get the
key/value pairs.  This is why subclassing MutableMapping makes casting
works, but unfortunately it breaks JSON dumping.

It will not suffice to create a stripped down C level class that returns non-zero on
`PyDict_Check()`, as the casting will iterate on the C level over that class' keys and values.

The only way to implement this transparently, is by implementing a C level dict like class, that does the
on-the-fly insertion of the key `default` and its value. It has to do so by faking a
length that is one bigger than the actual number of entries and
somehow implement indexing at the C level of `ma_keys` and `ma_values` to have that
extra item. If possible at all, that is going to be hard, as `dict_merge` assumes
fixed knowledge about quite a bit of the internals of the source object.

An alternative for fixing `json.dumps` is to fix `dict_merge`, but the latter would affect 
a lot of code negatively in speed, so that is less likely to happen (and also would not
be done retroactively on older versions of Python either).

Answer (score -1):

You can approach the problem in a completely different way. Instead of trying to produce a value when the key `'default'` is requested on the fly, you can initialize the dict with the key `'default'` set to your desired value, and then *protect* the value of the `'default'` key by overriding all the methods that can potentially alter the content of the dict so that the value of the key `'default'` is never altered:

```
class T(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['default'] = 'DEFAULT'
        super(T, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key != 'default':
            super(T, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if key != 'default':
            super(T, self).__delitem__(key)

    def clear(self):
        super(T, self).clear()
        self.__init__()

    def pop(self, key, **kwargs):
        if key == 'default':
            return self[key]
        return super(T, self).pop(key, **kwargs)

    def popitem(self):
        key, value = super(T, self).popitem()
        if key == 'default':
            key2, value2 = super(T, self).popitem()
            super(T, self).__setitem__(key, value)
            return key2, value2
        return key, value

    def update(self, other, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            if 'default' in kwargs:
                del kwargs['default']
        elif 'default' in other:
            del other['default']
        super(T, self).update(other, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is not adding the key "on the fly" as I indicated is necessary. That might do for this simplification of the problem, but not for the real thing.

Comment: Can you update your tester so that I can get a better understanding of what your expected "on the fly" behavior is?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with my tester. On-the-fly means that at the moment something starts iterating over the keys, or start copying the items etc, that extra values from somewhere else are added. You propose to add them to the dict instance itself beforehand, that is unacceptable (because in the real situation I need the dict without those additions as well).

Comment: What I mean is that you could write a test case with a scenario that shows how a non-on-the-fly solution wouldn't work, one that only an on-the-fly solution would work. Like you now mentioned, that you need the dict without those additions as well, so you should have a test case that shows how you use the dict without the additions. At the moment I still don't see under what condition you're going use the dict without the additions since you want to be able to cast `T` to dict with the additions too. You can't expect others to know what your "real situation" is without an example.

Comment: The complete class definition is over 400 lines and the question is getting too long as it is anyway as you can see from Aran-Fey's comment.  *adding e.g. a default key "on the fly"* together with the indicated solution that doesn't work for both cases, should be understandable by anyone familiar with that term, and is clearly different from adding a key permanently *up-front* as you do.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it effectively covers your on-the-fly end goals. Please try it out and let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this is not going to work at all. The line `kwargs['default'] = 'DEFAULT'` cannot be in the `__init__` function it assumes you can up-front get all the values. I cannot afford to have a copy of the "other" keys in this dict, there can be thousands, this has to be done *on the fly*. The keys that have to be put in *on the fly* are not fixed, they get determined when the instance items get iterated over. And of course the values for those keys are not guaranteed to be available before the start of the iteration either (otherwise it would not be *on-the-fly*).